# WCF: Failed to create a service

Tags: c#, mysql, wcf

I have a WCF service that was unable to make a database connection because I was using plain Sql instead of mySQL. So, I switched over in my code, and now when runnning I get the "Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata" error. Anyone know why this is happening? The client was running fine right before I made the switch, except was not making DB connection.

Here is my web config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
 <appSettings>
    <add key="ConnectString" value="server=xxx;database=xxx;uid=xxx;pwd="xxxx"/>
  </appSettings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
<httpRuntime/>
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>

      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
 </protocolMapping>
 <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
 </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your metadata can be made reacheable by adding the mex binding for you service.

**For https access**

```
<endpoint
      address="mex"
      binding="mexHttpsBinding"
      contract="IMetadataExchange"
      bindingConfiguration=""
      name="MexHttpsBindingEndpoint"/>
```

**For Http access**

```
<endpoint
      address="mex"
      binding="mexHttpBinding"
      contract="IMetadataExchange"
      bindingConfiguration=""
      name="MexHttpBindingEndpoint"/>
```